# Prepend timestamp to logfile only using tee and ts

Tags: bash, logging, tee

The following snippet prepends a timestamp with slightly different strings for stdout and stderr. That's not quite what i want though. How would it have to be modified to add timestamps to the logfile only, keeping output to the screen as-is?

```
LOGFILE=/var/log/a.log
exec 1> >(stdbuf -e0 -o0 ts '[%F %T] O:' | tee -a "$LOGFILE") \
     2> >(stdbuf -e0 -o0 ts '[%F %T] E:' | tee -a "$LOGFILE" >&2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a process substitution for the `tee` argument, instead of a file directly. Example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cat file | tee >(ts >> log.txt)
```

```
> bash test.sh
test1
test2
> cat log.txt
Oct 22 19:34:33 test1
Oct 22 19:34:33 test2
```

In your example, you redirect the outputs to `ts` first, and then to `tee`, so you will get timestamps into your console also.